# Moving web-inf/lib jars to Tomcat/myownlib during deployment

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat8, maven-tomcat-plugin

Thanks in Advance...
I have 7 webapps and want all respective WEB-INF/lib to be moved to Tomcat/myownlib.I know it can be done easily by copying them manually and configuring path in catalina.properties.It works fine.But expecting it should be done during deployment when war get unarchived or any suggestions also welcome to make it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do it automatically during tomcat undeploy. There is no directive or process in tomcat.

But you have tagged the question as "maven-tomcat-plugin" If you are using maven to perform the deploy and launch server there is an alternative you create a plugin or use one like AntRun, gmaven-plugin, to execute an step before deploy that copy all libs into the shared tomcat folder and restarts tomcat.

Important! Is required to restart tomcat after copy the libraries. Shared libraries are loaded on start only.

Example:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>run</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <tasks>
        <move file="from file" tofile="to file"/>
      </tasks>
    </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```